# Изменение макроса

Tags: vba, visual-basic

У меня Excel файл со встроенным макросом.
Нужно изменить его, но не удаётся войти в редактор для макроса, при нажатии `ALT+F11` макросы не открываются, все страницы распаролил - не помогло.
Сам файл открыт в режиме редактирования (не в режиме чтения).
Что нужно сделать, чтобы попасть в редактор макроса? - подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно сам VBA-редактор запоролен. Проверить можно так **TOOLS >> VBAProject Properties**, если попросит ввести пароль - то разгадка ясна.

Comment: @slippyk, спасибо большое! Проблема решена.

Comment: Опубликую тогда в качестве ответа, вдруг еще кому пригодится.

Comment: @slippyk, хорошо

Answer (score 1):

Возможно сам VBA-редактор запоролен. Проверить можно так **TOOLS >> VBAProject Properties**, если попросит ввести пароль - то разгадка ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте открыть ваш файл в ОпенОфисе и потом снова сохранить в исходном формате. Не исключено, что поможет.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Чем это поможет?

Comment: Не проверял, но мне казалось, что при этом макросы уничтожатся. Или нет?